# .FilterOn Method Not Working

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

K Access guru's. I have a module that requery's a main form, then set's a filter based on a value in a field, and requery's the subforms with that filter. The problem is when I set subform.FilterOn = True, it doesnt do anything and returns False. I'd rather not upload the whole solution. But heres a screenshot[image: screenshot] of the code with the highlighted part showing the discrepancy. Below is the code for copy/paste purposes. Why is this not working?

```
    Private Sub Combo7_AfterUpdate()
Dim strSQL As String
Application.Echo False
strSQL = "[APN] = " & Str(Nz(Me![Combo7], 0))
DoCmd.ApplyFilter wherecondition:=strSQL
Me![Combo22].Requery
Me![Combo22] = Me![Text24]

Dim val As String
Dim subform1 As Form
Dim subform2 As Form
Dim subform3 As Form
val = Me![Text24]

Set subform1 = Me.qPayment_subform.Form
Set subform2 = Me.qRefundWriteOff_subform.Form
Set subform3 = Me.qRetnCHK_subform.Form
subform1.FilterOnLoad = True
subform2.FilterOnLoad = True
subform3.FilterOnLoad = True
subform1.FilterOn = True
subform2.FilterOn = True
subform3.FilterOn = True
subform1.Filter = "PeriodID = " & val
subform2.Filter = "PeriodID = " & val
subform3.Filter = "PeriodID = " & val
subform1.Requery
subform2.Requery
subform3.Requery

Application.Echo True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are the subforms not linked to the main form record with Master/Child Links properties of the subform container control?

Comment: Try **first** setting `.Filter` and **then** `.FilterOn`.

Answer (score 0):

Give subform container control a name different from the object it holds. For instance, if the form is named frmOrderDetails name the container ctrDetails. Then maybe using the container name in setting the object variables will work. If not, consider eliminating the variables and just referencing the container name.

`With Me
...
.ctrDetails.Form.FilterOn = True
...
End With`

I know this means repeating .Form but it will be fast edit.

In any case, set the Filter property before FilterOn.
Also, FilterOnLoad and Requery are not necessary.